# Add a 30A 126V outlet for M/H (temp) plug in!

Tags: electrical

What to add a 30A 126V outlet in the garage to plug in motorhome sometimes.  Will 12-2 grounded wire work? Or what should I use? Thanks JR

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get the 126V specification?

Answer (score 1):

The 30A 120V RV receptacle is a rather unique thing.  Since is it 30A, you absolutely must use **10 AWG wire** and a 30A breaker.

However many RV owners can make do with 20A.  A breaker trip is a thing to be avoided. They simply use an adapter/cheater cable to get to a NEMA 5-20 plug.  They plug this into a NEMA 5-20 receptacle, which you will find familiar-looking.   This requires a 20A breaker and 12 AWG wire.   And yes, you can use it for other stuff the rest of the time, or even, at the same time.

[image: NEMA 5-20 Receptacle]

NEMA 5-20 Receptacle.  20A, 120V.

As isherwood points out, load is an issue.  Some RVs have less than 20A of fixed load, and are equipped with the 30A receptacle *only because that was the standard* for RVs.  Others may be built to pull *over* 20A, and on those, you'll need to be careful not to activate too many heating and/or cooking appliances.  Of course, plug-in loads can always push you over.  You can plug a power monitor like a "Kill-a-Watt" in between wall and RV to determine what you're pulling.  My Kill-a-Watt will helpfully beep if load is over 15A.  Really caught me by surprise, I didn't know they had audio.

Comment: The unsaid implication being that a 20A circuit may trip occasionally (or more often) if a bunch of appliances are used at once in the RV.